# How to rotate a 3D model based on the projection coordinates

Tags: c#, rotation, opentk

I'm trying to implement something using OpenTK in C# where when you render a 3d plot, you can rotate it around the z axis (pointing up) as I move the mouse.
I already have it working but as shown below, I had to come up with an arbitrary constant 500;
The equation is:

```
arc_length = radius * theta
theta = arc_length / radius
```

where `radius = eye_pos.Length`

arc_length is the delta_x in model coordinate, but
(e.X - mouse_down_pos.X) is in screen coordinate.
so that 500 was used to map model coordinate to screen projected coordinate.

QUESTION: is there a way to eliminate this constant and properly obtain the conversion factor?

My educated guess is that I should use somehow multiply [delta_x, 0, 0] by inverse of the projection matrix...but do not have a clue how.

```
private static Vector3 eye_pos = new Vector3(30.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
Matrix4 lookat = Matrix4.LookAt(eye_pos.X, eye_pos.Y, eye_pos.Z, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
...
private void glControl1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (mouse_op == Mouse_Operation.Rotate)
   {
      decimal yaw = (decimal)MathHelper.DegreesToRadians((e.X - mouse_down_pos.X) * 500 / eye_pos.Length) + ref_yaw;
       SetYawAndRedraw(yaw);

     }
}
```

[image]